# All divs has background blue.When I click on any div , background color has to change to red for only that div clicked & not others

Tags: jquery

But when you click on any one of div, the other divs remains blue and the clicked div has to changed to red only.How we implement using jquery ?

```css
.blue {
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div id="test1" class="blue"></div>
  <div id="test2" class="blue"></div>
  <div id="test3" class="blue"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

by using this keyword change the background color the current div

```
$(".blue").on("click", function() {
$(".blue").css("background-color","blue");
$(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

Comment: if you click on any one div , its changed to red but again if you click on any other div the remaining divs should be blue not red. so this doesnt help.

Comment: @AsmitGhatge check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aligoren/0j8fcbmz/

Comment: Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```js
$(".blue").on("click", function() {
   $(".blue").css("background", "blue")
   $(this).css("background", "red")
})
```

```css
.blue {
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1" class="blue"></div>
<div id="test2" class="blue"></div>
<div id="test3" class="blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either-

```
$('div').click(function(){
 $('.blue').css("background", "blue");
 $(this).css("background","red");
```

});

Or -

```
$('.blue').click(function(){
$('.blue').css("background", "blue");
$(this).css("background","red");
```

});

It will change the color of the div on which you have clicked.